# How to change shortcut to launch Search window from just Super/CMD on Macbook?

Tags: shortcut-keys, touchpad, mac

This is my third hour using Ubuntu and I'm pretty ticked off that whenever I just tap with four fingers on the track pad or just hit *Super* (known as *COMMAND* key to Macbook users), it brings up the Search window. Sure, it's not terribly bad but it is a nuisance. So how do I change it from just a simple press of the *Super* key to *Super+Space*, for example, like on Macbooks? Thank you.

Comment: uinty tweak tool -> unity -> additional -> launcher -> keyboard shortcuts -> show the launcher. watch tutorial here: 6:10
https://goo.gl/q7K5Tr

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings -> Text Input. On the bottom of the window you will see something like "Keyboard settings..." highlighted with orange letters. Click on that. It will take you to the Keyboard settings. There you can adjust all the keyboard shortcuts and add them if you like.

In order to change the keyboard shortcut, go to the category you want to choose, choose the shortcut and click on the key combination on that line. When you let the keys go, it will adjust the shortcut to your needs (e.g.: Super key -> Super key + Space)  If that key combination exists for another shortcut,  Ubuntu will automatically warn you about transferring the key combination (e.g.: Ctrl+Atl+Del) to another shortcut.

If you want any help, feel free to contact me.

Comment: I couldn't find the name of the shortcut to change from `Super` to `Super+Space` but what I did do and am really liking now is switch the Super key with the Control key, because Mac users use it much less often in macOS and on Macs it's in an uncomfortable position to be used so often.

Comment: @caliCoder OK!  I'm glad I helped!